# Interacting with google appengine from C#

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm writing a google appengine application, which stores data and has a web front end. I want to be ableto pull down this data in a C# program. This means I need to authenticate with the site (users must be logged in to view the data). How can I authenticate like this? I tried setting credentials on the WebClient but I keep getting the google login page.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
//should it be username@gmail.com ??

client.BaseAddress = "http://nosoperor-internal.appspot.com";

String s = client.DownloadString("/bank");
//s now contains the google login page, unfortunately
```

Comment: What kind of login scheme does your site employ? HTTP basic/digest, form+cookie?

Comment: I have no idea, whatever the default is for appengine

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in this blog:

[Accessing authenticated Google App Engine services from a .NET CF client](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=894)

and it works ^^

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you need to probably use [Google Data protocols](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html) and [account APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/index.html) to authenticate.

**Edit:** I would [download the .Net client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) and try the examples in there. This is a copy paste from the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/client-cs.html):

```
Service service = new Service("cl", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1"));
// Set your credentials:
service.setUserCredentials("jo@gmail.com", "mypassword");
```

Comment: hmm, that looks like it might be the answer, but I'm not sure. Any more details on this?

Comment: I think that you specifically want to look at the ClientLogin section: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

Comment: Thing is, I don't think my app counts as a service, presumably I would need to rewrite the application to deal with automated logins like this? I don't really know enough about web programming to be able to do that